# Norm of a matrix and lower bound for its determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, determinant, upper-lower-bounds

Assume that $M$ is a positive constant, $A=[a_{ij}]$ is a matrix, and $\vert a_{ij}\vert \geq M $ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$. Also, assume that $\det(A) \neq 0$ .Can we conclude that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\det(A) \geq CM$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. For instance, consider a matrix where every element is equal to $M$; its determinant will be zero.

Comment: What if we know the determinant is nonzero?

Comment: Then you can get arbitrarily close to zero. For instance, if $n=2$, you can get just perturb one element of the all-$M$ matrix slightly.

Comment: I thought maybe boundedness away from zero of the entries could prevent that possibly?

Comment: No. Consider: $$\det\begin{bmatrix}M&M\\M&M+\epsilon\end{bmatrix}=M\epsilon$$Let $\epsilon$ be as small as you need it to be.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. You can easily make a matrix with positive entries and negative eigenvalues. For instance, take a $2\times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 9 \\1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$